# Error with ekito/cron job tutorial

Tags: docker, cron

I think my error is so obvious, that I cannot see it at all.

I am trying to start a container described in: [Ekito example](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/)

I have copied/generated the contab and the dockerfile linke described and tried to run

```
sudo docker build --rm -t ekito/cron-example
```

But I get following error:

[image]

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `--rm` option from `docker build` command.

`--rm` is an option for `docker run`

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for answering so late.